# Difference between a value and operand

Tags: operators, expression, key-value, operands

The question is pretty simple, what is the difference between a value and an operand? They very similar however they must have a slight difference as they have different names.

Comment: An operand is involved in operations, so in `3+2`, 3 and 2 are operands. If you just have `3` (no operators like +) then the 3 is just a value.

Comment: @qrsngky would `"something"` and `"anotherthing"` be considered operands in the expression `"something" + "anotherthing"` and then the output `"somethinganotherthing"` be considered the value?

Comment: `"somethinganotherthing"` is the result of the operation. 
The operands and the result are values.

Comment: `The values combined are called operands, arguments, or inputs, and the value produced is called the value, result, or output.` (from Wikipedia). One can be more specific like, "the value of the operation" or "the value of the expression" when talking the output

Comment: alright so if I understand correctly, we can see operands as a subset of values basically.